# Python socket detecting the same ports open and closed in different parts of the code

Tags: python, sockets

When `choice == 6`, `socket` scans a certain port in an IP and prints if it's open.

When `choice == 9`,  `socket` scans a range of ports for a certain IP and prints which ones are open and which ones aren't.

When scanning the same IP and ports, though, those two scans show different results: if I scan ports from 1 to 99 in choice 9, only port 98 shows as closed and the rest are open, but in choice 6 all ports are shown as closed. Why is this happening?

```
    import socket
    import os
    import time
    #you must have figlet install in your system 
    while True : 
        print("\033[1;33;40m")
        os.system('figlet Socket') 
        time.sleep(0.1)
       
        print("1-Get ip by Host Name")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("2-Get port number By Name User Enter")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("3-GEt Name By Port Number User Enter")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("4-Get Host Name For Your Device")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("5-Get Internal Ip Address For Your Device")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("6-Check If Port Open Or not For Host You Enter")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("7-Convert Host Data To Network Short")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("8-convert Host Data To Network Long ")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Enter Any Other Key To Exit")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("-----------------------------------------------")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        choice = input('Enter Your Choice : ')
        if choice == "1":
            host = input("Enter Host Name : ")
            ip = (socket.gethostbyname(host))
            print(ip)
        elif choice == "2":
            name = input("Enter The Name Of Port YOu Want To know It's Number : ")
            port = socket.getservbyname(name)
            print(port)
        elif choice == "3":
            port1 = input("Enter Port Number To Get Name Of Port : ")
            name = socket.getservbyport(int(port1))
            print(name)
        elif choice == "4":
            print("Host Name For Your Devise Is : ", socket.gethostname())
    
        elif choice == "5":
            print("Internal IP Is : ", socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
        elif choice == "6":
            ip = input("Enter The IP : ")
            port = int(input("Enter Port To Check If it Open : "))
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            ip_port = (str(ip), port)
            result = sock.connect_ex(ip_port)
            if result == 0:
                print("Port Is Closed")
            else:
                print("port Is Open")
                sock.close()
        elif choice == "7":
            short = input("Please Enter The data you want to Transfare : ")
            rshort = socket.htons(int(short))  #Host To Network Short
            print(rshort)
        elif choice == "8":
            long = input("Please Enter The data you want to Transfare : ")
            rlong = socket.htonl(int(long))  #Host To Network Short
            print(rlong)
        elif choice == "9" :
             ip=input("Enter The ip You Want To scan ")    
             rang=int(input("Enter Range You want To scan "))
             x=0
             while x<rang :
                    sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                    ip_port = (str(ip), x)
                    result = sock.connect_ex(ip_port)
             if result == 0 :
                    print("port ",x,"is closed ")
                    x=x+1
             else :
                    print("Port ",x,"is opend")
                    x=x+1
            
              
        else:
            os.system('figlet GoodBye')
            time.sleep(1)
            os.system('clear')
            time.sleep(0.5)
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

From [`socket`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect_ex):

> `socket.connect_ex(address)`
>
> ...return an error indicator ... The error indicator is *0 if the operation succeeded*

Your code, however, treats the return value of zero as an indicator of failure to connect, while it actually is an indicator of *success* - of the port being *open*:

```
result = sock.connect_ex(ip_port)
if result == 0: # port OPEN!
    print("Port Is Closed")
else:
    print("port Is Open")
```

Comment: but what about condition 9 not make loop for all port why

Comment: @AdhamAshrafElganzoury, it's the same thing: you're treating `result == 0` as the port being closed, while in fact it's the exact opposite. Also, the indentation is off: the `if` statement is _outside_ the `while` loop, and thus the loop will never terminate

Comment: now I understand , thanks alot